# Taking out personal loan to pay salaries?

Tags: salary, new-job, termination, covid-19

I work in a small company, 16 people, central/western Europe.
 As many businesses, corona virus crisis hit us hard. Two people were fired and we were told, soon they might be firing more people, depending on the situation.
 Our boss (founder of the company) also told us, he took out a personal loan to pay this month salaries. He did not offer any more explanation. 
 The situation seems very volatile, I am already looking for a new job. 
 
My question is the following: 
 Why would anyone take out a *personal* loan, instead of taking the loan in company name? 
Does this show that he (the founder) is really invested in this company? 
 Does this loan automatically mean we are in deep, almost irreversible trouble that we are unlikely to recover from?

Comment: I am not sure that we can answer this here as it requires army of speculation, but broadly speaking unless business is well established and cashflow-heavy, it won't be getting any loans at all, at most they will get "business loan" that's personally guaranteed by the boss, which at most makes a tax difference, and not much else.

Comment: Or, maybe, the boss lied.

Comment: Under normal circumstances, the slightest hint of trouble with making payroll and the company is almost certainly doomed. Under the current situation, that's maybe not so clear. A business might be perfectly viable ordinarily, but still struggle in times of once-in-a-century global pandemic, and loans to survive long enough to get back to "normal" might make sense. It's very difficult to say.

Comment: An interesting situation presented in your question, but unfortunately, the question is very broad and is seeking opinions. This isn't the type of question generally accepted at The Workplace.

Comment: Why the hell would anyone close this? It's a great question.

Comment: OP, the answer is that as a rule small business *do not get* loans.  And yes, your company is about to go under - find a new job now.

Comment: I have done this (though I didn't tell the staff, mostly because I didn't want to scare them.) I have used a cash advance from my personal credit card to cover payroll, and vowed never to do it again, and done it again. I wouldn't do it if the trouble was irreversible -- I would need that liquidity to support myself after losing the company. I did it precisely because I knew that if I could keep my staff, I could get out of the hole. And I did.

Comment: I've used my money in emergencies, but not taken a loan. Boss is showboating a bit if not just making it up

Comment: I thought most countries offered a payday loan to companies suffering from covid-19. In the USA I think they set aside some money and it got used up pretty quickly so many businesses still can't make payroll. Overall though, my guess is if he took out a "loan" he probably kept a large portion of that for himself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why would anyone take out a personal loan, instead of taking the loan in company name?

Most likely because it was the only option available. Banks don't give loans without a collateral or some credible repayment. If the companies finances are really bad, it can't get a loan.

> Does this show that he (the founder) is really invested in this company?

Yes, depending on how accurate that statement is. Could also be that they are exaggerating to motivate or "guilt" people into staying, taking cuts or working harder. For example, if they took a $100 loan to supplement a $10000 payroll wouldn't mean much. If they took out the entire $10000 as a personal loan, that shows very deep commitment.

> Does this loan automatically mean we are in deep, almost irreversible trouble that we are unlikely to recover from?

Probably yes. Either your company is doing very poorly or your boss is lying: neither one bodes well. It's not all gloom and doom: if your boss is a reasonable and rational person, they wouldn't have taken out the personal loan if there weren't a reasonable chance to recover.

(edited)

Answer (score 4):

> Does this loan automatically mean we are in deep, almost irreversible trouble that we are unlikely to recover from?

Only your boss can really answer this question.

> Does this show that he (the founder) is really invested in this company?

Mostly, yes - provided the boss tells the truth. He sacrificed not only the initial investment, but he continues to sacrifice money.

> Why would anyone take out a personal loan, instead of taking the loan in company name?

Possibly because nobody would lend money in these times, to companies which look like being on the way to sink.

Comment: I'd caveat the "mostly, yes" bit with "...assuming he's telling the truth". Unscrupulous bosses might easily lie about the extent of their own investment in order to encourage their employees to invest and make sacrifices. Of course, lying or not, it won't be the employees that get the Ferrari if everything goes well.

Comment: @BittermanAndy: you are right, I missed that variant from sight. I updated the answer. Thank you. +1